# QGIS: Distance units in CRS layer: WGS 84

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

First post so please bear with me.

When I run a vector analysis on two shapefile layers with multiple points, I get a distance as my answer.  What are the units on this distance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit:* I assume you are using EPSG:4326 as CRS since it is the most common WGS84 CRS. If it is not the case, you should precise which CRS you are using based on the EPSG code.

Distances in a WGS84 (EPSG:4326) datum are not really meaningful since they are based on lon/lat units. If you want meaningful distances and if your points are not too far from each other, you should first reproject your layers in a UTM coordinates system (or simply perform an "on the fly" UTM CRS transformation).

Comment: For vector analysis, reprojecting the source data is safer than on-the-fly-reprojection.

Comment: so if I want to calculte ddistance between two points in WGS84, I must change it into UTM? otherwise I can't know the distance based on coordinates?